# Make onClick function that will switch textarea place

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

> ```
>       var counter=0; 
>      function appendText(){     
>      var text = $("#text").val();
> if ($("#text").val()){
> ```

```
var textArea = "<div> <textarea id='t"+counter+"'>"+text+
    "</textarea><button id='b"+counter+"' name='t"+counter+"' >edit</button> <button onClick='moveUp();'>Up</button></div>"; 


    $("#addedText").after(textArea);    
    $("#t"+counter).attr('readonly','readonly');    
    $("#t"+counter).attr('readonly','readonly');

    $("#t"+counter).css('width','500px');
$("#t"+counter).css('resize','none');
$("#t"+counter).css('background-color','#5CCCCC'); 
$("#t"+counter).css('font-weight','bold');             

$("#b"+counter).bind('click',makeAreaEditable);                  
counter++;  }   else{   }            };                                                                 


 var makeAreaEditable = function() {
 var target = event.target||event.srcElement||event.originalTarget;     
 var targetArea =$("#"+target.name);    
 targetArea.removeAttr('readonly');     
 var button =  $("#"+target.id);    
 button.text("OK");     
 button.unbind('click');
 button.bind('click',saveEdit); };

  var saveEdit =  function() {  
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;    
  var button =  $("#"+target.id);   
  button.text("edit");  
  button.unbind('click');
  button.bind('click',makeAreaEditable);    
  var targetArea = $("#"+target.name);  
  targetArea.attr('readonly', 'readonly'); };
```

I can't figure out how can i make the moveUp() function so that it would move textarea up one space. The textarea that is before should switch places with the one that you pushed the Up button.

The html looks like this:

```
 <textarea id="text" placeholder="baga text aici"></textarea> <button
 id="addText" onClick="appendText()" >Add text </button>        <div
 id="addedText" style="float:left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".moveup").on("click",function()   {
       var $divcontainer = $(this).parent();            
      if ( $divcontainer.prev().get(0))  $divcontainer.prev().before($divcontainer);

      });
//append whatever how many textarea & its up button in div.allthetextarea
```

html

```
 <div class="allthetextarea">
      <div><textarea/><input class="moveup"/></div>
      <div><textarea/><input class="moveup"/></div>
   ...
</div>
```

css

```
      .allthetextarea .moveup:first-child {display:none;}
```

Comment: I just want a button for each appended textareas that will make it move up one space and switch with the one before it

Comment: Of corse if it's not the first one

Comment: I created the button dynamicly <button onClick="moveUp()">Up<button>

Comment: @Paul so that's exactly what this code does; & get rid of this ugly onlcicke="", we are in 2013 not in 1993

Comment: i will keep that in mind... i am sure that you did a good job but i don't get the html code:-? from what i'm seeing it will make me, a textarea with this text inside it <input class="moveup"/>

Comment: @Paul i've put a / before the > because i'm lazy & we are supposed to have a minimum of knowledge `code <textarea /> = <textarea></textarea> ` gluck